# GROUP BY inverse (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to get the inverse of a group by statement in mysql?  My use case is to delete all duplicates.

Say my table looks like this:

```
ID | columnA | ...
1  |  A   
2  |  A
3  |  A
4  |  B
5  |  B
6  |  C
```

I want my result set to look like this:

```
ID | columnA | ...
2  | A
3  | A
5  | B
```

(Essentially this finds all duplicates leaving one behind.  Could be used to purge all duplicate records down to 1, or to perform other analysis later).

Comment: Your table do not have duplicates... What do you mean by "duplicates"?

Comment: The result set "you want" has duplicates (A exist two times)

Comment: How is this the inverse of group by? This is exactly what GROUP BY does, it combines all the duplicates into a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to take all but the first id for each value of `ColumnA`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id > (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.columnA = t.columnA);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should perform a lot better then inner select based queries.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
     TABLE 
 QUALIFY
     RANK() OVER (partition by columnA order by ID ASC ) = 1
```

EDIT : This apparently wont work in MySQL. Guess the only answer is to by a oracle license - or use another answer. ;)

Comment: Can MySQL do that?

Comment: Hm. Ill be danmed. I always see MySQL as having powerful syntax, but this is some serious weak sauce....

Answer (score 0):

Your result seems

```
 select max(id), columnA group by columnA
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my own solution based on @scaisEdge response before he edited it.  In need the opposite of my group by, so using a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM mytable GROUP BY columnA);
```

Comment: So you did want the query to return the duplicates, not the other way around... I think you just confused a couple of people.

Comment: The question says "leaving one behind". This solution removes 1 row from each group, so it will leave multiple rows behind.

Comment: Sorry my wording wasn't the best, but my example was correctly displaying what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I am confident this will help.

```
    create table test.temptable select distinct * from YourTable;
    truncate YourTable;
    insert into YourTable select * from test.temptable ;
```